# "Found cyclical <include> chain" error in XML layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a XML layout for my activity - let's call it `layout_a.xml` - which looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/layout_b"/>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_b"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `layout_b.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_details_list_entry_checkins_history_user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="34dip"
        android:layout_height="34dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_profilepic_medium"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_details_list_entry_checkins_history_user_avatar_provider_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_fb_small"
        android:layout_width="11dip"
        android:layout_height="11dip"/>
</FrameLayout>`
```

I get this error in Eclipse:

Found cyclical <include> chain: layout_a=>layout_b

Does anybody have a hint on what is causing it?

Comment: @dave.c: Thanks for formatting the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in ADT, please file a bug at http://b.android.com so that the Dev Tools team can look at it.

Comment: I just created a new [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14776&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). Thanks.

Comment: It was an issue related to a preview version of the ADT. It is gone on the stable version.

Answer (score 0):

You have two includes of the same file in layout_a. Remove one of them if you don't need it and it's there by mistake. If it's on purpose I'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: It is on purpose. The idea is that I do not want to copy and paste the same code twice. This is what the `<include>` element is about, innit?

Comment: I thought it would be for loading two frames which would imply loading pairs of pictures with the same ID. I tried to reproduce your error but didn't make it. Try cleaning your project and compile it again. On the top bar: Project->Clean...

Comment: I rely on project cleaning to solve weird compilation problems all the times but this time it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does the error go away if you give each include a unique @+id?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and fixed it by removing the `tools:layout="@layout/activity_customer_details"`

Not sure if this is a good practice. But it worked on both app and the IDE.